# Postback Issues with OnClick Events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code which is working fine, however; when I click delete button the event fires but the changes aren't displaying on PostBack. This obviously has something to do with PostBack managemment. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
   namespace WebApplication1
    {
        public partial class questiondetails : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadControls();
            }

        }

        void Edit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton editbut = sender as ImageButton;
            string cName = editbut.ID;
            string rID = cName.Remove(0, 5);

            Response.Write(Request.Form["entity_" + rID]);
            Response.Write(Request.Form["dollar_" + rID]);

        }

        void Delete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var delbut = (ImageButton)sender;
            string cName = delbut.ID;
            string rID = cName.Remove(0, 7);
            string MyParams = "@RowID=" + rID;

            iservices.DataAccessWebService WS = new iservices.DataAccessWebService();

            WS.ExecuteDatasetStoredProcedure(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityDataAccess"], "iweb_sp_custom_coi_Question_Delete", MyParams.ToString());
            LoadControls();
            Response.Write("dome");
      }


        protected void LoadControls()
        {

            //Construct paramters from Querystring
            StringBuilder MyParams = new StringBuilder();
            MyParams.Append("@Term=2013,@ProjectCode=a12345,@ID=123,@CategoryCode=CONSULTANCIES");

            //Count Answered questions
            iservices.DataAccessWebService WS = new iservices.DataAccessWebService();
            DataSet MyAnswers = WS.ExecuteDatasetStoredProcedure(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityDataAccess"], "iweb_sp_custom_coi_SelectCurrentQuestion", MyParams.ToString());



            foreach (DataTable dt in MyAnswers.Tables)
            {
                int rc = 0;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    //Generate unique controls from DS
                    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
                    tbx.ID = "entity_" + dr["rowID"].ToString();
                    tbx.Text = dr["EntityName"].ToString();
                    tbx.Width = 200;

                    DropDownList DollarRange = new DropDownList();
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("Select Dollar Amount");
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("Up to $1,000");
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("$1,001 - 5,000");
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("$5,001 - $10,000");
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("$10,001 - $50,000");
                    DollarRange.Items.Add("$50,001 - or more");
                    DollarRange.ID = "dollar_" + dr["rowID"].ToString();
                    DollarRange.SelectedValue = dr["DollarRange"].ToString();

                    ImageButton Delete = new ImageButton();
                    Delete.ImageUrl = "delete.png";
                    Delete.ID = "delete_" + dr["rowID"].ToString();
                    Delete.Click += Delete_Click;

                    ImageButton Edit = new ImageButton();
                    Edit.ImageUrl = "edit.png";
                    Edit.ID = "edit_" + dr["rowID"].ToString();
                    Edit.Click += Edit_Click;

                    //Append controls to placeholder
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((rc % 2 == 0) ? "<tr><td bgcolor='#f1f0e7'>" : "<tr><td>"));
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(tbx);
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((rc % 2 == 0) ? "</td><td bgcolor='#f1f0e7'>" : "</td><td>"));
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(DollarRange);
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl((rc % 2 == 0) ? "</td><td bgcolor='#f1f0e7'>" : "</td><td>"));
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(Delete);
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(Edit);
                    DataZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
                    rc++;
                }



            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, no data is returned. I checked the DB and the info is still there. If I load the page again with refresh both of my data reappears.

Comment: Does Delete_Click method fires when you click it on UI?

Comment: No. I moved the code to the page_load section and it fires and deletes the record, but my data is displaying before the revised data is processed so I am seeing old results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code, is that don't do LoadControls if it's not PostBack. When you add new control dynamically, it registers within page, so when postback for that control will be called - page will know what method it should call.

In your case when PostBack happens you don't call LoadControls, so Page doesn't know what method it should call, as there is no control at the moment when page is searching for control to handle current postback data.

If you will do LoadControls each time without checking for IsPostBack in PageLoad, then Delete_Click method will be called fine. But in may do two requests for data - one is for control filling at PageLoad, second one is for deleting and updated new data in Delete_Click method.

There is another moment with your code - you are adding controls to DataZone, which I suppose is asp:PlaceHolder, but you don't clear it, so controls can be duplicated for second LoadControls call. As usual you need to clear PlaceHolder before updating data in it.

Comment: In the Click event for the delete button I added
            DataZone.Controls.Clear();
            LoadControls();
It seems to be working. I am fairly new to placeholders so I was not thinking about clearing it but it makes sense. I also have LoadControls() registering every time. It seems to be working right now. Do you see any issues with my overall architecture? Any helpful tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Overall it seems ok. The only thing that you can also try to use Repeater\GridView controls, as they are used for such things. So you don't need to create controls dynamically. You just specify layout for each row, then load DataTable, set it to repeater.DataSource property, and call repeater.DataBind, and it will create all rows based on DataTable items and specified layout.